# Custom Encryption/Decryption for Spring-Cloud-Config Server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I am using spring-cloud-config server and trying to use the encrypt/decrypt feature. Is there a way we can customize the encrypt/decrypt feature i.e. we do have our own encryption standards and want to leverage those libraries.

Appreciate any help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to customize the encryption/decryption, essentially you need customize the `org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.TextEncryptor` bean by yourself.

Optimisticly, remove all the entrypt related configuration from your application.properties/application.yml, also you need make sure the JCE is not in your classpath, the main propose is disable the spring default encryption auto-configuration, then register your own `TextEncryptor` bean.

Here I add a very simple sample, so you can implement the `MyTextEncryptor` with your existing library.

**Sample**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Component
    static class MyTextEncryptor implements TextEncryptor {

        @Override
        public String encrypt(String text) {
            return "encrypt\n";
        }

        @Override
        public String decrypt(String encryptedText) {
            return "decrypt\n";
        }
    }
}
```

**Result**
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Reference:**

`org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.encrypt.EncryptionBootstrapConfiguration`
`org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.encrypt.EnvironmentDecryptApplicationInitializer`
`org.springframework.cloud.config.server.encryption.EncryptionController`

Comment: Thank you Liping for the pointer, I defined custom TextEncryptor but currently facing  issue  "{"status":"NO_KEY","description":"No key was installed for encryption service"}" when I curl on /encrypt endpoint. Will update once I get over this.

Comment: @Swappy I updated a very simle sample, hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Liping for code snippet. I wrote similar sample but returned the same function variable "text" from encrypt function (was just trying to get back the same value for testing). My observation is encrypt function gets called with value as "FOO" and if we return back "FOO" it gives "NO_KEY" error, however if incoming FOO is changed to some other value e.g. FOOBAR then encrypt function is called again with actual value to be encrypted.