# Spring cloud config server property encryption

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-config

Can I use encrypted properties on config server side ? My endpoints for encryption / decryption works fine.

I have component on server side, which need to decrypt property from application.properties, but it is not decrypted.

userPassword={cipher}120bae33...

Any suggestion what is wrong ? I am using symmetric key provided by env property.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Encryption/Decryption for Spring-Cloud-Config Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39952528/custom-encryption-decryption-for-spring-cloud-config-server)

Answer (score 0):

Try placing your encrypt.* configuration in bootstrap.properties (or bootstrap.yml).  The problem is this:

> `EncryptionAutoConfiguration` is loaded as a `BootstrapConfiguration`, therefore the keystore information must go in bootstrap.yaml

Reference: [spring-cloud-config issue #762](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/762)